# Fixing UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment in python

Tags: python

Reading a text file with names and birthdays in a function printBook(), returning name, birthday and referencing it later on in another function I get:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment

Code:

```
with open("scratch.txt") as file:

    def printBook():
        for line in file:
            name, month, date = line.split(",")
            print("Name:", name, "    Month:", month, "    Date:", date)
        return name, month, date

    def givenMonthPrintsElse(monthGiven):
        obj = printBook()
        if monthGiven == obj[1]:
            print("Name:", obj[0], "Day:", obj[2])

    printBook()
    givenMonthPrintsElse("Feb")
```

Comment: What happens if there are no lines in the file?

Comment: What do you want it to return?  The last name, month and date?

Comment: @chris i've got a specific file i'm working on there so didn't think of preventing this

Comment: @SimonCrane yes return name, month, date that could be used later in other functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is already an accepted answer, I believe it does not deal with the real issue in the question.
[Elton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60263065/12818877) will prevent the exception from being thrown, but will not render the desired output, from what I understood of the question.

## The Real Issue

The issue here is that when calling the `printBook()` function inside the `givenMonthPrintsElse()` function, there is nothing left to read in the file, therefore leading to no `line` objects, which skips the `for` loop, returning three unassigned variables (`name`, `month` and `date`).

This happens because the `with ... open` statement is misplaced. Once the `file` object is read on the `printBook()` function, the *cursor* is at EOF (end of file), thus nothing left to be read. Calling again another function that requires the output of `printBook()` under the same `with ... open` statement results in empty output. You can confirm this by commenting out the first call to `printBook()`, and you should get the desired output.

## Solution (okay)

The simplest way I can think that solves it is moving the `with ... open` statement inside the `printBook()` function, like this:

```py
def printBook():
    with open("scratch.txt") as file:
        for line in file:
            name, month, date = line.split(",")
            print("Name:", name, "    Month:", month, "    Date:", date)
        return name, month, date


def givenMonthPrintsElse(monthGiven):
    obj = printBook()
    if monthGiven == obj[1]:
        print("Name:", obj[0], "Day:", obj[2])


printBook()
givenMonthPrintsElse("Feb")
```

An important remark here is that, although it solves the issue, I suppose this is not the **real** intent of the OP, since it only allows to use the **last** line of the file (even though it reads through all of them). That is because `name`, `month` and `date` are overwritten at each iteration/line of the file, and only the last ones are returned by `printBook()`.

## Solution (better)

So, as following, a simple structure allows to access any line of the file:

```py
def fileToList(fileName):
    with open(fileName) as file:
        values = file.readlines()
    return values


def printNameDate(fileList, monthGiven, entry=1):
    if monthGiven in fileList[entry-1]:
        name, month, date = fileList[entry-1].split(",")
        print("Name:", name, "\nDay:", date)


book = fileToList("scratch.txt")
printNameDate(book, "Feb")
```

This way, in the `book` object you have a list of the content of all the lines, as strings, that afterwards you can split and process as desired. The `printNameDate()` function uses a list of strings (as the one returned by `fileToList()` and a line number (named `entry`)) to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the name variable inside the for loop and accessing outside (in the return statement).

The easiest way to solve this is by declaring the variables before the for loop, so the `printBook` function would be something like:

```
def printBook():
    name, month, date = None, None, None
    for line in file:
        name, month, date = line.split(",")
        print("Name:", name, "    Month:", month, "    Date:", date)
    return name, month, date
```

PS: As @Chris pointed out, the problem isn't just because you're accessing the variables outside the loop (python accepts it), but because when the loop doesn't run, your variables aren't declared.

Comment: Actually, declaring the variables inside the loop works fine. Loops don't create a new scope. The problem is that _if the loop doesn't run_, the variables don't get created.